# How to create an executable file from java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to know how to create an executable file with a setup wizard and so on.
I knew how to create a jar file but there is some additional files and scripts I want them to be with the program.

I need my code with its interface to be a real program can be installed.

Comment: see answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: Since Java is interpreted, the user must have Java RTE installed.